# Скомпилировал приложение на Python. Как задать путь к файлу в скрипте, чтобы он запускался на любом ПК?

Tags: python, macos, компиляция, файловая-система, сборка

Скомпилировал код в приложение на Python через py2app. По ходу скрипта нужно открыть .txt файл и вытянуть из него инфу:

```
with open('/Users/projects/Project/credentials.txt', 'r') as file:
    reader = file.read()
```

Вопрос: если я отправлю приложение на иной ПК (после создания дистрибутива, например), то путь к моему .txt файлу изменится, разумеется. Как решить эту задачу?
Как задать путь к файлу, чтобы он запускался на любом ПК?

Comment: Использовать относительные пути?

Comment: Относительно чего? Некоторые не напишут воркинг дир в ярлык, а маин лежит в темпе на некоторых компилятора. Сис.аргв[0] тоже надо смотреть где окажется...

Answer (score 1):

Первое - лучше использовать относительный путь от `init.py`.

Второе - создать установщик, который будет генерировать независимый от условностей пользователя на windows путь, в котором будет сохранён нужный `.txt` файл.

Comment: Крайний случай - os.getlogin( ).

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос следующим образом.
Первый вариант:

```
import os
file_path_credentials = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'credentials.txt')
with open(file_path_credentials, 'r') as file:
    username = file.read()
    file.close()
```

Второй вариант:

```
import os
file_path_username = os.path.abspath('credentials.txt')
with open(file_path_credentials, 'r') as file:
    username = file.read()
    file.close()
```

Всем спасибо за наводки!